# Autorest rest client code generator not working for XML response type

Tags: xml, swagger, autorest

I am trying to use swagger 2.0 and https://github.com/Azure/autorest (Autorest ) to generate a C# code for a Rest Enspoint. They work fine if API service response type is `application/json` but if it is `application/xml` it fails during the deserialization of the response to the object. I believe it is because of the xmlns(namespace does not have an object by itself). Has any one tried using `autorest` on a service which send mediatype application/xml and had success?

Any example would help
here is the error i get

```
Unable to deserialize the response. Newtonsoft.Json: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0

Autorest veresion is : AutoRest code generation utility [version: 2.0.4283; node: v10.15.3]
```

Here is the xml file, I am creating endpoint for. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.13-beta-1/junit-4.13-beta-1.pom

and i created the swagger 2.0 schema from a bunch of tools.

```
swagger: '2.0'
host: repo1.maven.org
schemes:
  - https
info:
  description: API Program description
  title: Maven Registry Client
  version: 1.0.0
basePath: /maven2/
paths:
  '/{groupPath}/{artifactId}/{version}/{pomFile}':
    get:
      description: Gets Maven package details
      summary: Gets Maven package details
      externalDocs:
        description: Maven registry API documentation
        url: 'https://mvnrepository.com/'
      operationId:  GetPackageDetails
      produces:
        - application/xml
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          schema:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Maven"
      security: []
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: groupPath
          description: Path of the Group
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: path
          name: artifactId
          description: Artifact Id
          required: true
          type: string          
        - in: path
          name: version
          description: Version of the Package
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: path
          name: pomFile
          description: Pom File of the package file
          required: true
          type: string   
definitions:
  Maven:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      '@schemaLocation':
        type: string
        format: uri
      modelVersion:
        type: string
      groupId:
        type: string
      artifactId:
        type: string
      version:
        type: string
      name:
        type: string
      description:
        type: string
      url:
        type: string
        format: uri
      inceptionYear:
        type: string
        format: integer
      organization:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Organization'
      licenses:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Licenses'
      developers:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Developers'
      contributors:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Contributors'
      mailingLists:
        $ref: '#/definitions/MailingLists'
      prerequisites:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Prerequisites'
      scm:
        $ref: '#/definitions/SCM'
      issueManagement:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Management'
      ciManagement:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Management'
      distributionManagement:
        $ref: '#/definitions/DistributionManagement'
      properties:
        $ref: '#/definitions/MavenProperties'
      dependencies:
        $ref: '#/definitions/MavenDependencies'
      build:
        $ref: '#/definitions/MavenBuild'
      reporting:
        $ref: '#/definitions/MavenReporting'
      profiles:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Profiles'
    title: Maven
  MavenBuild:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      resources:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Resources'
      plugins:
        $ref: '#/definitions/PurplePlugins'
    title: MavenBuild
  PurplePlugins:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      plugin:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/PurplePlugin'
    title: PurplePlugins
  PurplePlugin:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      artifactId:
        type: string
      version:
        type: string
      executions:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Executions'
      groupId:
        type: string
      configuration:
        $ref: '#/definitions/PurpleConfiguration'
      dependencies:
        $ref: '#/definitions/PluginDependencies'
    title: PurplePlugin
  PurpleConfiguration:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      ignoreMissingFile:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      file:
        type: string
      outputFile:
        type: string
      regex:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      token:
        type: string
      value:
        type: string
      encoding:
        type: string
      source:
        type: string
      target:
        type: string
      testSource:
        type: string
      testTarget:
        type: string
      compilerVersion:
        type: string
      showDeprecation:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      showWarnings:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      debug:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      fork:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      compilerArgs:
        $ref: '#/definitions/PurpleCompilerArgs'
      maxmem:
        type: string
      test:
        type: string
      useSystemClassLoader:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      enableAssertions:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      stylesheetfile:
        type: string
      show:
        type: string
      author:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      version:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      detectLinks:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      linksource:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      keywords:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      use:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      windowtitle:
        type: string
      locale:
        type: string
      javadocVersion:
        type: string
      javaApiLinks:
        $ref: '#/definitions/JavaAPILinks'
      excludePackageNames:
        type: string
      verbose:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      minmemory:
        type: string
      maxmemory:
        type: string
      failOnError:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      includeDependencySources:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      dependencySourceIncludes:
        $ref: '#/definitions/DependencySourceIncludes'
      mavenExecutorId:
        type: string
      useReleaseProfile:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      arguments:
        type: string
      tagNameFormat:
        type: string
      archive:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Archive'
    title: PurpleConfiguration
  Archive:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      addMavenDescriptor:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      manifest:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Manifest'
      manifestEntries:
        $ref: '#/definitions/ManifestEntries'
    title: Archive
  Manifest:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      addDefaultImplementationEntries:
        type: string
        format: boolean
    title: Manifest
  ManifestEntries:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      Automatic-Module-Name:
        type: string
    title: ManifestEntries
  PurpleCompilerArgs:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      arg:
        type: string
    title: PurpleCompilerArgs
  DependencySourceIncludes:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      dependencySourceInclude:
        type: string
    title: DependencySourceIncludes
  JavaAPILinks:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      property:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Property'
    title: JavaAPILinks
  Property:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      value:
        type: string
    title: Property
  PluginDependencies:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      dependency:
        $ref: '#/definitions/DependencyUnion'
    title: PluginDependencies
  DependencyElement:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      groupId:
        type: string
      artifactId:
        type: string
      version:
        type: string
      scope:
        type: string
    title: DependencyElement
  Executions:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      execution:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Execution'
    title: Executions
  Execution:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      phase:
        type: string
      goals:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Goals'
      configuration:
        $ref: '#/definitions/ExecutionConfiguration'
    title: Execution
  ExecutionConfiguration:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      fail:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      rules:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Rules'
      signature:
        $ref: '#/definitions/DependencyElement'
    title: ExecutionConfiguration
  Rules:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      requireMavenVersion:
        $ref: '#/definitions/RequireVersion'
      requireJavaVersion:
        $ref: '#/definitions/RequireVersion'
      requireNoRepositories:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Require'
      requireReleaseDeps:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Require'
    title: Rules
  RequireVersion:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
      version:
        type: string
    title: RequireVersion
  Require:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
    title: Require
  Goals:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      goal:
        type: string
    title: Goals
  Resources:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      resource:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Resource'
    title: Resources
  Resource:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      directory:
        type: string
      includes:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Includes'
    title: Resource
  Includes:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      include:
        type: string
    title: Includes
  Management:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      system:
        type: string
      url:
        type: string
        format: uri
    title: Management
  Contributors:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      contributor:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Contributor'
    title: Contributors
  Contributor:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      organization:
        type: string
      email:
        type: string
      url:
        type: string
        format: uri
      roles:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Roles'
    title: Contributor
  Roles:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      role:
        type: string
    title: Roles
  MavenDependencies:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      dependency:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/DependencyElement'
    title: MavenDependencies
  Developers:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      developer:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Developer'
    title: Developers
  Developer:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      name:
        type: string
      email:
        type: string
    title: Developer
  DistributionManagement:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      downloadUrl:
        type: string
        format: uri
      snapshotRepository:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Repository'
      repository:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Repository'
      site:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Site'
    title: DistributionManagement
  Repository:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      name:
        type: string
      url:
        type: string
        format: uri
    title: Repository
  Site:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      url:
        type: string
    title: Site
  Licenses:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      license:
        $ref: '#/definitions/License'
    title: Licenses
  License:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      url:
        type: string
        format: uri
      distribution:
        type: string
    title: License
  MailingLists:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      mailingList:
        $ref: '#/definitions/MailingList'
    title: MailingLists
  MailingList:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      post:
        type: string
      archive:
        type: string
        format: uri
    title: MailingList
  Organization:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      url:
        type: string
        format: uri
    title: Organization
  Prerequisites:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      maven:
        type: string
    title: Prerequisites
  Profiles:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      profile:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Profile'
    title: Profiles
  Profile:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      build:
        $ref: '#/definitions/ProfileBuild'
      activation:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Activation'
      reporting:
        $ref: '#/definitions/ProfileReporting'
      properties:
        $ref: '#/definitions/ProfileProperties'
    title: Profile
  Activation:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      jdk:
        type: string
    title: Activation
  ProfileBuild:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      plugins:
        $ref: '#/definitions/FluffyPlugins'
    title: ProfileBuild
  FluffyPlugins:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      plugin:
        $ref: '#/definitions/PluginUnion'
    title: FluffyPlugins
  FluffyPlugin:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      artifactId:
        type: string
      executions:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Executions'
      configuration:
        $ref: '#/definitions/FluffyConfiguration'
    title: FluffyPlugin
  TentacledPlugin:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      artifactId:
        type: string
      version:
        type: string
      executions:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Executions'
    title: TentacledPlugin
  FluffyConfiguration:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      compilerArgs:
        $ref: '#/definitions/FluffyCompilerArgs'
      additionalparam:
        type: string
    title: FluffyConfiguration
  FluffyCompilerArgs:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      arg:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
    title: FluffyCompilerArgs
  ProfileProperties:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      jdkVersion:
        type: string
    title: ProfileProperties
  ProfileReporting:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      plugins:
        $ref: '#/definitions/TentacledPlugins'
    title: ProfileReporting
  TentacledPlugins:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      plugin:
        $ref: '#/definitions/StickyPlugin'
    title: TentacledPlugins
  StickyPlugin:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      artifactId:
        type: string
      configuration:
        $ref: '#/definitions/TentacledConfiguration'
    title: StickyPlugin
  TentacledConfiguration:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      additionalparam:
        type: string
    title: TentacledConfiguration
  MavenProperties:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      jdkVersion:
        type: string
      surefireVersion:
        type: string
      hamcrestVersion:
        type: string
      project.build.sourceEncoding:
        type: string
      arguments:
        type: string
      gpg.keyname:
        type: string
    title: MavenProperties
  MavenReporting:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      plugins:
        $ref: '#/definitions/StickyPlugins'
    title: MavenReporting
  StickyPlugins:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      plugin:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/IndigoPlugin'
    title: StickyPlugins
  IndigoPlugin:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      artifactId:
        type: string
      version:
        type: string
      configuration:
        $ref: '#/definitions/StickyConfiguration'
      reportSets:
        $ref: '#/definitions/ReportSets'
    title: IndigoPlugin
  StickyConfiguration:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      dependencyLocationsEnabled:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      destDir:
        type: string
      stylesheetfile:
        type: string
      show:
        type: string
      author:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      version:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      detectLinks:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      linksource:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      keywords:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      use:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      windowtitle:
        type: string
      encoding:
        type: string
      locale:
        type: string
      javadocVersion:
        type: string
      javaApiLinks:
        $ref: '#/definitions/JavaAPILinks'
      excludePackageNames:
        type: string
      verbose:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      minmemory:
        type: string
      maxmemory:
        type: string
      failOnError:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      includeDependencySources:
        type: string
        format: boolean
      dependencySourceIncludes:
        $ref: '#/definitions/DependencySourceIncludes'
    title: StickyConfiguration
  ReportSets:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      reportSet:
        $ref: '#/definitions/ReportSet'
    title: ReportSets
  ReportSet:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      reports:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Reports'
    title: ReportSet
  Reports:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      report:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Report'
    title: Reports
  SCM:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      connection:
        type: string
      developerConnection:
        type: string
      url:
        type: string
        format: uri
      tag:
        type: string
    title: SCM
  DependencyUnion:
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: '#/definitions/DependencyElement'
    title: DependencyUnion
  PluginUnion:
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: '#/definitions/FluffyPlugin'
    title: PluginUnion
  Report:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
    title: Report
```

Comment: What version of AutoRest do you use? Can you post you API definition (or a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) so that others can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I am using Autorest version AutoRest code generation utility [version: 2.0.4283; node: v10.15.3]

Comment: Please post your Swagger 2.0 definition (JSON or YAML) and a sample XML response that fails to be serialized.

Comment: Thanks Helen the Endpoint is https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.13-beta-1/junit-4.13-beta-1.pom , the autorest creation is for this rest endpoint

Comment: Sorry I still don't follow. AutoRest generates code from an [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/) (Swagger) definition file which describes a REST API. The linked file is a [POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) which has nothing to do with OpenAPI/Swagger.

Comment: Is the URL `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.13-beta-1/junit-4.13-beta-1.pom` the actual endpoint (request URL) that you want to generate a client for? If so, you first need to create an OpenAPI definition file (in the YAML or JSON format) that describes that endpoint - see https://swagger.io/docs/specification/basic-structure/ for a start. Then you would use that file with AutoRest.

Comment: Thanks Helen , yes you are rite, we are using swagger 2.0 and attached is the swagger doc, but still having trouble getting things work on the deserlization part. also here is the autorest parameter i used - base-folder: src/MavenClient input-file: swagger.yaml output-folder: generated namespace: MavenClient csharp: true use-datetimeoffset: true use-internal-constructors: true enable-xml: true